# How to handle Python exceptions when no action is desired

Tags: python-3.x, exception

IN python the following syntax is generally the way to handle an exception is a `SystemExit` is possible.

```
try:
    execute some command here
except SystemExit:
    take a different course of action here
```

However, I want to use exception handling in a way where no alternate course of action is taken.  In general I just want to prevent the `SystemExit` and continue the program execution.  I tried the following, but it only works when inside a for loop

```
try:
    execute some command here
except SystemExit:
    continue
```

How can I execute this general code block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the pass statement:

```
try:
    execute some command here
except SystemExit:
    pass
```